# Update 1 product user defined field with the value from another product

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am looking for procedure I can run to make sure these fields match. The main item number does not end in v, but we have a variation of that number that ends in v. we need the user_def_1 to match. I am not that great in sql, I could handle this with a VB program or excel macro but I would like it to be a store procedure so I can schedule it to run nightly. any help is apprecaited

Item Table

Item_no | user_def_1

80001   |  325

80001V  |  needs to match the 325 above

Answer (score 0):

You want to pair the "V" rows with their non-"V" brethren. That can be accomplished with an `inner join` of the table with itself. Once you have that working it is a simple matter to `update` one side of the pair from the other side.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Items as Table ( ItemNo VarChar(16), UserDef1 VarChar(64) );

insert into @Items ( ItemNo, UserDef1 ) values
  ( '80001', '325' ),
  ( '80001V', 'needs to match the 325 above' ),
  ( '80001V', 'nothing to see here' ),
  ( '80002V', 'Vogon poetry' ),
  ( '80002', 'BR549' );

select * from @Items;

-- Practice matching main/variant pairs.
select MainItem.ItemNo as MI_ItemNo, MainItem.UserDef1 as MI_UserDef1,
  VariantItem.ItemNo as VI_ItemNo, VariantItem.UserDef1 as VI_UserDef1
  from @Items as MainItem inner join
    @Items as VariantItem on MainItem.ItemNo + 'V' = VariantItem.ItemNo;

-- Update the variant(s).
update VariantItem
  set UserDef1 = MainItem.UserDef1
  from @Items as MainItem inner join
    @Items as VariantItem on MainItem.ItemNo + 'V' = VariantItem.ItemNo and
      -- No need to update rows that already have the correct value.
      MainItem.UserDef1 != VariantItem.UserDef1;    

-- See if it worked.
select * from @Items;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lFECrS0b).

Left as an exercise is wrapping the code in a suitable stored procedure.